# hide/unhide rows based on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Based on a cell value = true or false, I conditionally formatted rows to turn black.  That means that I need to scroll down to find the set of rows that did not turn black.  I would prefer that all my rows with data remain unexpanded and remain hidden and only expand when cell value = true.  Is there a way to unhide the few, select rows when the cell value = true and compress/hide if cell value=false - without using macros; or any macro code suggestion if one is needed.  This will forego the scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Macros would be needed.  The code would not be difficult to write.

**Edit #1**:

Here is a small sample macro.  It assumes that column **A** from **A1** thru **A100** contains either True or False.  If the value is False the row is hidden, otherwise it is made visible:

```
Sub HideOrShowRows()
    Dim A As Range
    Set A = Range("A1:A100")
    A.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    For i = 1 To 100
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Cells(i, 1).Value = False Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Raystafarian.....the question was..."is it possible"........the answer is "no"

Comment: I agree with the others. You could at least provide a sample VBA code as alternative

Comment: @nixda  You are probably correct.........my **EDIT** provides a sample with the assumptions behind the sample.