# Hide rows based on the value of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

First, I've tried these threads, to no avail ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/725762/hide-unhide-rows-based-on-cell-value), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/663441/vba-code-to-hide-or-unhide-rows-based-on-a-cell-value), and others which I am prohibited to mention since my rank doesn't allow for more than two links). I am almost certain I'm just missing some simple detail.

1. What I'd like to do is automatically comb through column A (A2:A25, to be exact) and if the cell is empty, to simply hide the entire corresponding row.
2. Even better, would be to only hide the corresponding E cell, and leave the rest of the row untouched.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried applying a filter? Or do you have a reason for wanting to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: It wasn't my intention to reinvent the wheel, and I don't explicitly have a reason to reinvent the wheel either. I'm not quite sure how applying filters could address my problem. Could you specify what you would do exactly?

Comment: Apply a filter to column A and show everything but blanks. That will accomplish goal 1. I'm pretty sure goal 2 is not possible, even with VBA.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Just wanted to let you know that what you suggested works quite nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It will loop through A2:A25 (let me know if that range can change and I can make this more flexible) and hide the row of any cell in that range that is empty. There is not a simple way that I know of to hide single cells, not does that make sense to me. If you have a table of data, nothing would coincide with the row it should, at least visually.

```
Sub Hide_Rows()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 25 To 2 Step -1
If Range("A" & i) = "" Then
   Rows(i).Hidden = True
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, as far as I can tell, this code solves the first problem (1).  

It would still be really useful to have problem (2) solved. I tried editing the code to:  

`Sub Hide_Rows()  
Dim i As Integer  
For i = 25 To 2 Step -1  
If Range("A" & i) = "" Then  
   Columns("E").Hidden = True  
End If  
Next i  
End Sub` 

However it ends up hiding the entire "E" column even if there is a non-empty value in column "A".

Comment: Correct, because you hide the column, not the row. As far as I know, there is no way to hide a single cell.

Comment: Exactly, that's too bad. It strikes me as odd that there's no sort of switch capability, like if cell x has value y then do this to cell z. And then just apply that to multiple cells, like you would by dragging down a formula in one cell to apply to many. Is this perhaps possible via a formula? Sorry if what I'm saying is nonsensical. 

I also found the some code entitled "Clear Content of adjacent cells where cell in Column G appears blank" which, if it does what I think it does, should achieve the desired affect. Since the individual cells I want cleared (ideally: hidden, not cleared) ↓

Comment: are adjacent to blank cells. The code is too long for this comment box, but the rest can be found here: http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/delempty.htm

`Sub MoAli1()
  'Clear out values in Gx:Mx when value in col G appears empty
  'see http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/delempty.htm 2000/07/29
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Dim cell As Range
  For Each cell In Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("g:g"), _
         ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If Trim(cell.Value) = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 6)).ClearContent`

Comment: Given what I know about Excel, hiding one cell is what doesn't really make sense to me. I can't figure out why this would be desired. Coding VBA to clear the contents of a cell next to a blank cell would be a simple task.

Comment: I see. Let me briefly explain why it is desired. My spreadsheet is a simple list of titles in one column, dates in another, and a URL in the third column. If the title cell is empty, then I only want to hide the URL cell and leave the others untouched. So that when other people view the spreadsheet they see that the date is there, but that the cell which which would contain the title is empty. In other words, using the code that has been suggested could leave me with a sheet that is completely empty if there happens to be a sheet with no values in the title cells. This is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use specialcells for example.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Range("A2:A25").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

You can hide the entire row, you can't hide just on cell in a column.

Comment: This works well, but a check should be added to make sure there are cells in `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`, otherwise an error will occur if there are no blank cells.